# Galería de elementos de desigual alto con distribución uniforme

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy usando la API de `Twitter` para obtener los últimos 6 tweets pero todos ellos vienen con alturas diferentes.

Quiero hacer un grid donde ponga los 6 tweets y que se distribuyan uniformemente sin tener espacios en blancos.

Intenté usar este código en el contenedor de los tweets:

```
column-count: 5;
column-gap: 15px;
column-fill: auto;
```

pero creo que hay una manera mejor de hacerlo.

Esta es la distribución a la que quiero llegar:

[image: La distribución a la que quiero llegar]

Comment: Hola Gabriel. Qué problema tienes? puedes poner el HTML que te genera para ver el resultado que tienes ? Estas pidiendo otras maneras de distribuir los tweets ?

Comment: Aparte del código estaría bien que explicaras con más detalle la distribución que quieres lograr ¿Todos en una fila?¿En columnas, cuántas columnas?

Comment: He puesto una imagen para que mirais donde quiero llegar

Comment: Masonry, hay una librería llamada Masonry que te soluciona esto en 0,5. https://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

Hace mucho tiempo desde que se formuló esta pregunta. Lo más seguro es que ya hayas encontrado una solución, pero de todas maneras no está de más situar una respuesta por si puede ser útil para alguien más.

Si conoces el número de items y de columnas, es relativamente sencillo crear un efecto [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/) usando [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceptos_Basicos_de_Flexbox) y un poco de `JavaScript`. El truco consiste en distribuir los elementos por columnas, pero cambiando su orden para dar la impresión de filas, y después ajustar la altura del contenedor dándole el valor más grande que alcanzarían las columnas formadas por el número de elementos deseados. Al ajustar el alto del contenedor, la propiedad `flex-wrap` distribuye los elementos en diferentes columnas en vez de en una sola (en tu caso como son seis elementos en total y quieres distribuirlos en tres columnas, pues cada columna contaría con dos elementos).

Aquí tienes un snippet que muestra este concepto en funcionamiento:

> Debes tener en cuenta que si tu *layout* es responsivo, debes actualizar la altura del contenedor en cada redimensión, tomando en cuenta los nuevos tamaños de los elementos.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const boxes = container.querySelectorAll('.box');

// Actualizar el orden para hacerlo más similar a filas en vez de a columnas
boxes.forEach((b, i) => {
  b.style.order = i % 3;
});

// Actualizar el alto del contenedor
// Teniendo en cuenta la mayor suma de cada columna
// Como son seis elementos y tres columnas, pues el máximo de elementos por columna es dos
const heights = Array.prototype.reduce.call(boxes, (h, b, i) => {
  const o = i % 3;
  h[o] = h[o] || 0;
  h[o] += b.offsetHeight;
  return h;
}, []);
container.style.height = `${Math.max(...heights)}px`;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 0;
  width: 33.3333%; /* 33.3333% es para tres columnas */
}

.inner {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  flex: 1 0;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Dar altos diferentes a los elementos */
.box:nth-child(1),
.box:nth-child(3),
.box:nth-child(5) {
  height: 100px;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  height: 200px;
}
.box:nth-child(4) {
  height: 150px;
}
.box:nth-child(6) {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inner">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inner">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inner">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inner">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inner">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inner">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```